# Aplicação Multi-tenancy Spring-mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Boa noite galera, faz duas semanas que estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação multi-tenancy com spring mvc, mas só acho com spring boot, porém sem sucesso. Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.
Quero fazer uma aplicação utilizando spring-mvc onde eu possa acessar um banco de dados pela url ex: www.url-aplicacao.com/noma_database.

Peço por favor se alguém tiver uma solução, me ajude.